# Google sheets Error 401 , I can't add/edit data on spreadsheet

Tags: android, google-sheets-api

I am creating an Android app that reads data from a google spreadsheet & takes new values from user input to update/create a row or more in the same spreadsheet.

Actually, within the same app I can successfully access the data from the spreadsheet using GET method, receiving a JSON object and takes the required data using the following code:

```
String requestUrl = https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/A1:F200?key={myAPIkey}
URL url = createUrl(requestUrl);
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
try { urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.connect(); } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
```

But, the problem that I get Error 401 when I am trying to write the user data to the same spreadsheet using "POST" method, I am using the following code to connect:

```
String requestUrl = https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/A5:F5:append?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&key={myAPIkey}

URL url = createUrl(requestUrl);

HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        try {
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

            OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());

            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            out.write(object);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
} finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
```

Could you help me why I get error 401 & how can I add my data to a google spreadsheet ?

I have set my spreadsheet privacy to public & anyone can edit with link but I get the same error.

Comment: Can you paste the entire contents of the 401 response?

Answer (score 1):

I expect the problem is that you're not passing any authentication.  A 401 is an "UNAUTHORIZED" response.  Reads can be down without authorization if the spreadsheet is public, but writes from the API require authorization, even if the spreadsheet is public.

You should consider using the [Sheets API client libraries](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/android), which simplify the work for you and make authentication easier.